# Is all of the 4GB of internal memory on a basic Xbox 360 Slim model usable?

Tags: xbox-360

On the newer [Xbox 360 Slim models the base 4GB internal memory version ($199)](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/Xbox360/Consoles/Systems/Xbox3604gb), is the full 4GB of internal memory usable, or is some of it partitioned for other uses like the dashboard software, etc.? If it's not all usable, how much is left over for use for profiles, save games and other items?

I know that on my older 20GB hard drive model, only about 13-14GB of space were actually usable after formatting and dashboard software and whatnot.

Comment: My guess is all 4GB are available as flash memory, as if you had a memory cartridge in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually remember hearing something about this a while back. I think you actually end up with a little over 3GB of space if you delete some demos that come with the system. Not sure I can come up with a link with proof though.

Ahh, here is a link to the Amazon review mentioning you end up with about 3.2GB of flash space.

http://www.amazon.com/review/R3IA7K9X9350RE/ref=cm_cr_dp_cmt?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B003O6JKLC&nodeID=468642

Comment: There is the file system overhead, a mandatory 512MB block for Xbox 360 OS stuff and more space for other caches.